# Hello, I am new to python. When I try to import aliens from aliens.py, the entire code of aliens.py prints out. Anyone who can help me out here?

Tags: list, import

[Screenshot from alien.py and aliens.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNLN6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The module statements are executed only the first time the module name is encountered in an import statement. You can find a much detailed explanation about modules [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)